# How get root url path

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, url

I'm searching a way to get the root URL of my Web project; as example:

### Local:

http://localhost:52390/pages/user.aspx

Expected result: http://localhost:52390

### IIS:

http://lst.pg.com/iLearn/pages/user.aspx

Expected result: http://lst.pg.com/iLearn

Exists a way to achieve this in ASPX? Or in Javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASPX: `Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath`

Implemented with Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rootUrl = '<% =(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath) %>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

in javascript you can get url information from the location object.

```
var href = location.href; //returns the entire url
var host = location.hostname; //returns just the hostname of the url.
```

Comment: With href = http:// localhost:52390/pages/user.aspx; with host = localhost

Comment: Correct. Once you have that information you can easily split the string to get the portion you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are times I need to get the rootpath from the code behind. Here is what I use.

```
public static string GetRootPath()
{
    HttpContext CTX;
    CTX = HttpContext.Current;
    return CTX.Request.ApplicationPath.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is that Javascript?

Comment: C#. The person posting was asking how to do this is JavaScript or APX (.NET Forms). This will get the path during a server side call.